# AppleScript: How to automate creating a new note in Apple Notes

Tags: macos, applescript

I'm trying to automate quickly creating new notes in the `Notes.app` and I would like to open my newly created note in a single floating window.

Here's my code for creating the note:

```
set RunTime to ((current date)) as string
tell application "Notes"
    activate
    tell account "iCloud"
        make new note at folder "Notes" with properties {name:RunTime}
        --does not work
        --open document {name:RunTime}
    end tell
end tell
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

**Notes** doesn't have scripting commands for the `selection` per se, but the `show` command will select the specified note in the process of showing it.  There also isn't a command to use Notes' floating window, but GUI scripting can be used to choose that menu item, for example (Mojave):

```
set example to (current date) as string
tell application "Notes"
    activate
    tell folder "Notes" -- or whatever
        set theNote to make new note with properties {name:example} -- 'make' returns a reference to the new note
    end tell

    try
        (* If not making a new note, existing notes can be referenced by using id or name properties:
                set theNote to note id "xyz" -- id property
                -- or --
                set theNote to note example -- name property
                -- or --
                tell (get every note whose name is example) -- filter form
                    if it is {} then error "A note named \"" & example & "\" was not found."
                    set theNote to its first item
                end tell
        *)
        show theNote -- also selects the note
        delay 0.25
        tell application "System Events" to click menu item "Float Selected Note" of menu "Window" of menu bar item "Window" of menu bar 1 of application process "Notes"
    on error errmess -- not able to get the note
        log errmess
        display alert "Error getting note" message errmess
    end try
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

The following AppleScript opens the newly created RunTime note.

```
tell application "Notes"
    tell account "iCloud"
        make new note at folder "Notes" with properties {name:"RunTime", body:"RunTime body"}
        set noteRunTime to get notes whose name is "RunTime"
        show item 1 of noteRunTime
    end tell
end tell
```

If you know the id of a note you can open it using the following AppleScript.

Before executing the script you need to set appropriately the values of the variables noteID and myAccount.

```
set noteID to "x-coredata://05A6F727-5F0B-478F-A493-B2DFAEA12067/ICNote/p153"
set myAccount to "iCloud"

tell application "Notes"
    tell account myAccount
        set aNote to get notes whose id is noteID
        if aNote is {} then display dialog "The note was not found."
        show item 1 of aNote        
    end tell
end tell
```

Moreover you can get the id of a note using the following script. The id is copied to the clipboard.

```
tell application "Notes"
    activate
    set noteNames to name of notes
    set chosenNote to (choose from list noteNames)
    if (chosenNote is false) then error number -128 -- Cancel button.
    set aNote to get notes whose name is item 1 of chosenNote
    set noteID to id of item 1 of aNote
    set the clipboard to noteID
    display dialog "The id of the selected note is " & noteID
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, worked for me

```
set example to ("New Note") as string
tell application "Notes"
activate
tell folder "Notes" -- or whatever
    set theNote to make new note with properties {name:example} -- 'make' returns a reference to the new note
end tell

try
    (* If not making a new note, existing notes can be referenced by using id or name properties:
            set theNote to note id "xyz" -- id property
            -- or --
            set theNote to note example -- name property
            -- or --
            tell (get every note whose name is example) -- filter form
                if it is {} then error "A note named \"" & example & "\" was not found."
                set theNote to its first item
            end tell
    *)
    show theNote -- also selects the note
    tell application "System Events" to click menu item "Float Selected Note" of menu "Window" of menu bar item "Window" of menu bar 1 of application process "Notes"
    close back window
on error errmess -- not able to get the note
    log errmess
    display alert "Error getting note" message errmess
end try 
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

```
set noteContent to ¬
    "I'm trying to automate quickly creating new notes in the Notes.app
 and I would like to open my newly created note in a single floating window.
Here's my code for creating the note:"

set noteTitle to "Quickly created new note" & linefeed

set noteHTMLText to ¬
    "<pre style=\"font-family:Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:20;bold:false\">" & ¬
    noteContent & ¬
    "</pre>"

tell application "Notes" to tell account "iCloud"
    -- make new note
    set theNote to make new note at folder ¬
        "Notes" with properties {name:noteTitle, body:noteHTMLText}
    -- get its id
    try
        id of theNote
    on error errorMessage
        set ATID to AppleScript's text item delimiters
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "\""
        set theID to text item 2 of errorMessage
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ATID
    end try
    -- show created note to select it
    set theDoc to show note id theID of folder "Notes"
end tell

-- open created note in a single floating window
tell application "Notes" to activate
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Notes" to ¬
    click menu item "Float Selected Note" of menu 1 of ¬
        menu bar item "Window" of menu bar 1
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Notes.app AppleScript suite does not support opening notes in a new document as Safari does for example.
2. Standard suite contains *document*, however, you need to work with it outside of *tell account "iCloud"* inside *tell application "Notes*
3. Your last hope might be *open note location {url}* while using noteID

   ```
   set noteID to make new note at folder "Notes" with properties {name:RunTime}
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
tell application "Notes"
    tell account "iCloud"
        tell folder "Notes" -- you can remove this to show notes from any folder
            show note 1 -- notes are indexed by their last edited date
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to figure out how to refer to notes by their name or id. The answers above no longer seems to work. If someone knows how, let me know.

Comment: Are you talking about something other than `show note named "the name"` or `show note id "the id"`?

Comment: I have now figured out how to refer to notes by their name. However, I Can't figure out how to refer to notes by their id. @red_menace

Comment: You would get the id by either looking it up (name, index, etc) or getting it when it is created, then use `note id "the id"`.

Comment: I've tried that, and I couldn't get it to work. I think there must be a bug. Could you see if you can get it to work with a simple script that displays a note with a specific id?

Comment: This seems to be moving away from being an answer. I've added an answer to the original poster's question (although they haven't been around for a while) that may help.